# Why Github desktop does not want to work with your private repositories?

Tags: github

I apologize for my English. (Translated in google translate)

There are private repositories on Github. authorization via SSH. working with them through Bash or the Git Source Tree. recently Source Tree - began to "blunt" much, I decided to use the Github Desktop GUI. but no matter what I do I can't get access to private repositories using the Github Desktop GUI. very strange thing is that the Github Desktop GUI without problems works with private repositories bitbucket and his misses.. Tell me someone faced this problem ?

Private repository on GitHub: 
Github Desktop - not working, 
Git Bash - working 
Source Tree - it works

Private repository on BitBucket : 
Github Desktop - working , 
Git Bash - working
Source Tree - it works

Why Github does not provide access to your repositories ?

[github desktop error private repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lWOF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myzP9.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by server side security settings. 
I've had similar issue with Visual Studio Online. Github desktop could not connect using Username and Password used to login via web interface. Solution was to use token generated by VSO and supplied to GitHub desktop in password field. Another option in VSO was to activate alternative credentials, but recommended approach is token.
I did not work with private repositories of GitHub so do not know if it has similar mechanism, so you will need to check it.